# Why does QGIS 2.4 prematurely terminates on startup at "Starting Python"?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqt

After reinstalling Python (3.4) as well as OSGeo4W and the QGIS Standalone, my QGIS always crashed when "Starting Python" on my Windows 7 64 Bit environment. It simply did not proceed to the QGIS-GUI to be of any use. Furthermore, this happened on the way:

As I was beginning to write a plugin for QGIS, I faced a problem where the ui-compiler for qt-uis wouldn't work without telling it where the PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH is. As advised in a post here on gis.stackexchange, I set the respective system variables and added PYTHONHOME to my PATH-variable as well. The two steps ui-compilation worked, the test-plugin was finally ready but... QGIS refused to start as mentioned.

No errors are thrown/logged.

**How do I get Quantum GIS 2.4 Chugiak back to work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the problems seems obvious now but didn't get to me because of all the small changes and trial and error analysis made on the way:

Setting PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH (seemingly only PYTHONPATH) caused to program to terminate on startup without errors. Deleting them solves the problem.

I was fooled by the fact that QGIS as well as other programs in the OSGeo4W software package are initialized by the use of batch-files, which modify the system variables. Through a folder-wide, I've found parts of the bath-script like this one `if "%PYTHONPATH%" == "" set PYTHONPATH=%GISBASE%\etc\python`. The PYTHONPATH-variable is overriden only when it is not already defined which it was in my case.

This provides a second solution to the problem:
Set the PYTHONPATH-variable in e.g. the qgis.bat-file: `set PYTHONPATH=%GISBASE%\etc`.

The mentioned ui-compilation won't work again if the systemwide changes of PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME are redone. This can easily be solved by setting these variables and the PATH-variable in an extra bat-file and starting the compiling-scripts from there.