# QGIS crashes when starting Python, unless opened in administrator mode

Tags: qgis, python, environment-variable

I am using QGIS 3.14.16 and I believe, I have somehow corrupted my QGIS/Python interaction.

**My Problem:**
When I open QGIS and the status information reads "Starting Python", the application just closes. No error message, it is just gone. When I start in administrator mode however, it all works fine.

**How I ruined the setup**
I had it running just fine after the initial installation. I then changed the PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME variables in QGIS to try to work on a virtual environment on my system. After restarting QGIS, it would not start again. I have not added any System or User Variables in the Windows settings.

**How I tried to fix it**
I have uninstalled and deleted all files associated with QGIS twice now, but whenever I reinstall the problem is the same. QGIS is now installed in *C:\Program Files\QGIS*.
I checked the file *\QGIS\bin\qgis-bin.env* and PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH look fine to me:

```
PYTHONHOME=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS\apps\Python37
PYTHONPATH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS\apps\Python37;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS\apps\Python37\Scripts
```

The content in *\QGIS\bin\p3_env.bat* also looks fine to me:

```
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37
SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONHOME%;%PYTHONHOME%\Scripts
PATH %PYTHONPATH%;%PATH%
```

**My research**
I found [this](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33966) unresolved Bug, which describes someone messing with PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME as well and consequently resulting in QGIS crashing. I believe he changed the variables not within QGIS (what I did), but within his User Environmental Variables. After deleting them, it worked for him again.

I found a similar bug [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118044/why-does-qgis-2-4-prematurely-terminates-on-startup-at-starting-python) where the solution again was to delete environment variables. Again, I did not set any windows environment variables.

As I said, starting in administrator mode is possible, but this is not my preferred option. I want to make sure that my setup is well defined. Additionally I have encountered problems when working with "Actions", which might be related to this problem.
Does anyone have ideas, what might cause the troubles? Any suggestions on what to try?

Comment: Dont have an answer, but does "uninstalled and deleted all files" also include your QGIS user profile within C:/Users...? Usually this should reset all settings made in QGIS.

Comment: I believe I did that, but to be entirely sure I will do the same thing now again and let you know.

Comment: Wow, I don't believe it... There were some QGIS profile settings in C:Users\Me\Appdata\Roaming which I apparently did not find before (when searching for QGIS in the file explorer...). After deleting everything there, it works again! Thank you so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to also delete your QGIS profile located at `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles`. This should reset all settings you have made in QGIS. After you deleted this folder, you can reinstall QGIS clean and freshly.

Note that `AppData` folder is hidden by Windows by default. [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files) is how to show them.

On linux it should be located at `/home/USER/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles` and on MacOS `~/Library/Application\Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles`.